# PHP If conditional still executing

Tags: php, internet-explorer, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a basic PHP if conditional, it works perfectly in all browsers apart from Internet Explorer. With Internet Explorer it still executes the conditional even if it is not met.  Am I missing something?

```
<?php
$logo = trim($row_BBSession['cover_logo']);

if($logo != "" || $logo != "undefined"){
    echo "<div id=\"frontLogo\">";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: PHP is independent of a web browser as it is executed server side. You need to post the html / javascript code that triggers your PHP script to get an answer to this

Comment: Exactly, I thought it would be browser independent as it's server side. But, there is no html / javascript triggering this - it just runs on the page.

Comment: And how is `$row_BBSession` filled then?

Comment: As a sidenote, your condition makes no sense.

Comment: Switch your condition to if( $logo !== "" && $logo !== "undefined" ), although I suppose what you want is if( $logo !== "" && $logo !== null )

Comment: It's pulled from a database.

Comment: My mistake, I was running an OR when I meant to have AND. Changing to && and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how it can work anywhere. There is a flaw in the logic: basically, you are asking PHP to execute the conditional if:

```
logo is not ""
OR
logo is not "undefined"
```

which will always be `true` (one of the conditions will necessary be satisfied).

Try with:

```
if not ($logo != "" || $logo != "undefined")
```